# Reindexing MultiIndex pivot table in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to reindex my pivot table, to get a chain of daily indexes. Currently the index looks like this:

You can see level one is monthly periodicity from the beginning for some series and daily for other.

```
MultiIndex([('1919-01-31', 'PX_LAST', 'M', '2099-12-31'),
            ('1919-02-28', 'PX_LAST', 'M', '2099-12-31'),
            ('1919-03-31', 'PX_LAST', 'M', '2099-12-31'),
            ('1919-04-30', 'PX_LAST', 'M', '2099-12-31'),
            ('1919-05-31', 'PX_LAST', 'M', '2099-12-31'),
            ('1919-06-30', 'PX_LAST', 'M', '2099-12-31'),
            ('1919-07-31', 'PX_LAST', 'M', '2099-12-31'),
            ('1919-08-31', 'PX_LAST', 'M', '2099-12-31'),
            ('1919-09-30', 'PX_LAST', 'M', '2099-12-31'),
            ('1919-10-31', 'PX_LAST', 'M', '2099-12-31'),
            ...
            ('2020-06-02', 'PX_LAST', 'D', '2099-12-31'),
            ('2020-06-03', 'PX_LAST', 'D', '2099-12-31'),
            ('2020-06-04', 'PX_LAST', 'D', '2099-12-31'),
            ('2020-06-05', 'PX_LAST', 'D', '2099-12-31'),
            ('2020-06-06', 'PX_LAST', 'D', '2099-12-31'),
            ('2020-06-07', 'PX_LAST', 'D', '2099-12-31'),
            ('2020-06-08', 'PX_LAST', 'D', '2099-12-31'),
            ('2020-06-08', 'PX_LAST', 'W', '2099-12-31'),
            ('2020-06-09', 'PX_LAST', 'D', '2099-12-31'),
            ('2020-06-30', 'PX_LAST', 'M', '2099-12-31')],
           names=['date', 'type', 'frequency', 'expiration_date'], length=42368)
```

I'm getting a start & end date for my daily index, like this (piv_table is my pivot table):

```
start_date = piv_table.index.min()
end_date = piv_table.index.max()
```

Having that I need to create a list of daily datetime objects, like this:

```
new_dates = pd.date_range(start_date[0], end_date[0], freq='D')
```

Next, I'm reindexing the data:

```
new_pivot = piv_table.reindex(new_dates,level=0).ffill()
```

But literally nothing happens, my new_pivot table is still the same. Index has not change to incorporate daily change. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my sample data:

```
date    type    frequency   expiration_date ADP LEVL Index  ADS BCI Index
1/31/1919   PX_LAST M   12/31/2099  2   3
2/28/1919   PX_LAST M   12/31/2099      
3/31/1919   PX_LAST M   12/31/2099      
4/30/1919   PX_LAST M   12/31/2099      
5/31/1919   PX_LAST M   12/31/2099      
6/30/1919   PX_LAST M   12/31/2099      
7/31/1919   PX_LAST M   12/31/2099      
8/31/1919   PX_LAST M   12/31/2099      
9/30/1919   PX_LAST M   12/31/2099      
10/31/1919  PX_LAST M   12/31/2099      
11/30/1919  PX_LAST M   12/31/2099      
12/31/1919  PX_LAST M   12/31/2099      
1/31/1920   PX_LAST M   12/31/2099      
2/29/1920   PX_LAST M   12/31/2099      
3/31/1920   PX_LAST M   12/31/2099      
4/30/1920   PX_LAST M   12/31/2099      
5/31/1920   PX_LAST M   12/31/2099      
6/30/1920   PX_LAST M   12/31/2099      
6/1/2020    PX_LAST D   12/31/2099  23  2342
6/1/2020    PX_LAST W   12/31/2099      
6/2/2020    PX_LAST D   12/31/2099      
6/3/2020    PX_LAST D   12/31/2099      
6/4/2020    PX_LAST D   12/31/2099      
6/5/2020    PX_LAST D   12/31/2099      
6/6/2020    PX_LAST D   12/31/2099      
6/7/2020    PX_LAST D   12/31/2099      
6/8/2020    PX_LAST D   12/31/2099      
6/8/2020    PX_LAST W   12/31/2099      
6/9/2020    PX_LAST D   12/31/2099      
6/30/2020   PX_LAST M   12/31/2099
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'chain of daily indices'? Could you please add the expected output (and perhaps a small data sample that is the input for this output)?

Comment: Just added. Basically, I would like to have a daily dates in my 'date' column, which is a part of MultiIndex described.

Comment: I think I understand the input - but what's the expected output? You want to have all the dates (e.g. Jan 1st, Jan 2nd, Jan 3rd, etc)? What data should there be in the other columns?

Comment: @Roy2012 exactly.. Just all the dates, the rest of index levels should be the same.. Actual data in columns should be forward filled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

```
min_date = df.reset_index()["date"].min()
max_date = df.reset_index()["date"].max()

all_dates = pd.date_range(min_date, max_date, freq="D")
all_dates.name = "date"

pd.DataFrame(index=all_dates).join(df.reset_index().set_index("date")).sort_index().fillna(method="ffill")
```

The result is (I don't have values for index, ADS, and BSI):

```
               type frequency expiration_date  ADP  LEVL  Index  ADS  BCI  \
date                                                                        
1919-01-31  PX_LAST         M      12/31/2099  2.0   3.0    NaN  NaN  NaN   
1919-02-01  PX_LAST         M      12/31/2099  2.0   3.0    NaN  NaN  NaN   
1919-02-02  PX_LAST         M      12/31/2099  2.0   3.0    NaN  NaN  NaN   
1919-02-03  PX_LAST         M      12/31/2099  2.0   3.0    NaN  NaN  NaN   
1919-02-04  PX_LAST         M      12/31/2099  2.0   3.0    NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: This is working pretty well. However, I need to find some way to not loose 'ticker' which is needed to stack the data.

Comment: what do you mean by 'ticker'?

Comment: I have created new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62390142/reindexing-and-stacking-the-data-with-multiindex